# How to remove dashed underlines in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, warnings, underline

VSCode is showing dashed underlines on lines of code. I understand that they are warnings, but would like them not to reflect at all as they make the code difficult to read and therefore debug. I've gone through the suggestions settings and turned them all off, but it has not fixed the problem. I have also googled extensively but can only seem to find an answer on how to remove whitespace highlighting, which I tried just in case but also did not work. Please advise what can be done to remove underlining.

[Dashed Lines Example #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceSmU.png)
[Dashed Lines Example #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUFhL.png)

Comment: do you see dashes when you select a different theme, and when all extensions are disabled

Comment: Yes still reflect when changing themes. Not sure how to disable extensions. It also strikes through my code when using certain terms, like event. I'd like to get rid of all lines, dashes, strike throughs, pop-ups, etc.

Comment: Definitely do `Developer: Reload with Extensions Disabled` from the Command Palette and see if the lines disappear.  That does not look like built-in vscode behaviour.

Comment: you can use the option Mark suggests or use a command line option (see doc)